# <a> inside an image alt attribute? (using UniteGallery which diplays "alt" as the image title)

Tags: html, anchor, alt

I'm not good enough in JavaScript/jQuery to make my own gallery or modify an existing one. I'm using UniteGallery script which provide a nice looking tiles style gallery.

The problem is that I wanted a link to be displayed when the image is zoomed. And the only diplayed text when the image is clicked on, is the `alt` attribute.

So I'm wondering if I can put an `<a>` tag inside the `alt` attribute of the image. I know it's not what `alt` attribute should be for, but W3C validator doesn't seem to mind about that.

```
<img alt="Image 1 Title <a class='button' href='project1.html' target='_blank'>More</a>"
src="img/gallery/thumbs/image1.png" data-image="img/gallery/image1HD.png" data-description="Image 1 Description"/>
```

Do you think that's ok? (I don't even know what the `data-description` is used for in unitegallery.) If you got any other solution, I'll be glad to read it.

Comment: So what happens when you do this? does it work as you expect it to?

Comment: accordlying to the `img` docs: `ALT: This attribute defines the alternative **text** describing the image. Users will see this text displayed if the image URL is wrong, the image is not in one of the supported formats, or if the image is not yet downloaded.`

Comment: Yes, it does work, and display the link. I haven't tried to stylised it as a button but it shouldn't cause any issue.

I know the alt attribute should be the description of the image, and it will kinda be.. but with a link next to it.
I just never used a tag inside any attribute before and it doesn't really feel right to do it.

Comment: "And the only diplayed text when the image is clicked on, is the alt attribute." That's bizarre. Is that a feature of Unite Gallery? It sounds like it's misusing the alt attribute altogether.

Comment: Yes, it's the default UniteGallery behavior...  I'm now thinking about using masonry/isotope with FancyBox instead. It would probably work well for what I want to do and I already used them in the past.